# how to pass ClaimsIdentity when page redirect to another ASP.Net mvc 4.7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, session-cookies, claims

it seems like User.Identity is not persistent and only valid in one HttpContext, so when the application site redirect to another page (example from "/" to "/events") the User.Identity is lost and i need to recreate it or access from session/cookie.

However im kind of new to ASP.NET MVC, so i have no idea how to pass ClaimsIdentity across sessions, i used OpenId connection with 3rd party provider, and i created/set the ClaimsPrincipal mysel.

Any suggestion how to do this?